# Generic Task That Consume/Produce HTTP RS in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, generics, javafx-8

## Desired Code

I need to find a generic way to send http request with jersey-client plus the method should use `JavaFX Task` to avoid freezing of UI. This is what i have so far

## Generic Rest Service

```
public class RestService<T> {

private String path;
private Class<T> entityClass;

private static final String WS_URI = "http://localhost:8080/api";

public RestService(Class<T> entityClass,String path) {
    this.path=path;
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

public T save(T t){
    Client client = null;
    try {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseUri());
        return  (T)target.path(path).request()
                .post(Entity.entity(t, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), entityClass);

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally { if(client != null) client.close(); }
}

public T update(T t) throws RuntimeException {
    Client client = null;
    try {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseUri());
        return  (T)target.path(path).request()
                .put(Entity.entity(t, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), entityClass);
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally { if(client != null) client.close(); }
}

public ObservableList<T> findAll(){
    Client client = null;
    try {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseUri());
        return target.path(path).request()
                .get(new GenericType<ObservableList<T>>(){});
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally { if(client != null) client.close(); }
}

public T delete(Integer id) throws RuntimeException {
    Client client = null;
    try {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseUri());
        return (T)target.path(path+id).request().delete(entityClass);
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally { if(client != null) client.close(); }
}

public T findOne(Integer id) throws RuntimeException {
    Client client = null;
    try {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseUri());
        return target.path(path+id).request().get(entityClass);
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally { if(client != null) client.close(); }
}


}
```

What i cannot figure out is creating another class that will call individual methods in a generic manner. The point is to have a single method for each `CRUD` operations that works in `JavaFX Task` thread

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public class MyTypeRestService extends RestService<MyType>
```